# Unable to pull imgaes via K8s cluster from nexus private repo

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nexus, cicd

I am trying to setup CI/CD pipeline where I am trying to pull the image form docker private repo and its failing while creating the deployment via kubernetes with below error:

```
Failed to pull image "34.125.222.46:8083/springapp:69": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "34.125.222.46:8083/springapp:69": failed to resolve reference "34.125.222.46:8083/springapp:69": failed to do request: Head "https://34.125.222.46:8083/v2/springapp/manifests/69": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

But I am able to pull the image using docker pull `34.125.222.46:8083/springapp:69`.

I have added the nexus repo url in daemon.json as insecure registry as below

```
"insecure-registries":["34.125.222.46:8083"]
```

and also I have created a secret named as registry-secret which has the nexus repo url , username and password which then I referred into k8s deployment manifest file.

Can anyone help me with this issue please.
Thanks in advance.

I tried create a deployment using the images pushed to my nexus repo but the deployment is failing as it is unable to pull the image.
whereas I am successfully able to pull the image using docker pull.

Comment: you need to restart docker / nexus / blah after change  daemon.json

Comment: Does this [git issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/28321#issuecomment-638307611) help you to resolve your issue?.

Comment: @Mate Thanks for your suggetsion. I have tried it but no luck.

Comment: @SaiChandraGadde I have tried the resolution provided on the link but still the same issue.
I am able to pull the image when I try it with docker pull directly but pod is unable to create with the same image.

Comment: Did you set [image pull policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#referring-to-an-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod), Once check this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#referring-to-an-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod) for your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for this issue. My kubernetes container runtime was containerd which I am not sure why instead docker as I have not installed containerd.
So I had to update the config.toml for containerd to refer the nexus registry.
Post that I was able to pull the image from nexus registry successfully.